# All blocks read same global memory location section. Fastest method is?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, nvidia, broadcast

I am writing an algorithm which all blocks are reading a same address. Such as we have a list=[1, 2, 3, 4], and all blocks are reading it and store it to their own shared memory...My test shows the more blocks reading it, the slower it will be...I guess no broadcast happen here? Any idea I can make it faster? Thank you!!!

I learnt from previous post that this can be broadcast in one wrap, seems can not happen in different wrap....(Actually in my case, the threads in one wrap are not reading a same location...)

Comment: If you only read from that location, you could try to use constant memory, but I wouldn't bet on performance improvements. In the end you will need to provide enough computation to hide the memory latency. The broadcasting on the warp level happens inside a SM. With multiple blocks the mechanism that should help is just caching. With `__ldca` you could tell the compiler explicitly to cache at all levels (See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ldx-functions)), but that should be the default anyway.

Comment: As multiple blocks are not guaranteed to be scheduled at the same time in general (neither are multiple warps), so broadcasting doesn't really make sense for them. The threads of one warp are (normally) running in lockstep so broadcast makes sense there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once list element is accessed by first warp of a SM unit, the second warp in same SM unit gets it from cache and broadcasts to all simt lanes. But another SM unit's warp may not have it in L1 cache so it fetches from L2 to L1 first.

It is similar in `__constant__` memory but it requires same address to be accessed by all threads. Its latency is closer to register access. `__constant__` memory is like instruction cache, you get more performance when all threads do same thing.

For example, if you have a Gaussian-filter that iterates over same coefficient-list of filter on all threads, it is better to use constant memory. Using shared memory does not have much advantage as the filter array is not scanned randomly. Shared memory is better when the filter array content is different per block or if it needs random access.

You can also combine constant memory and shared memory. Get half of list from constant memory, then the other half from shared memory. This should let 1024 threads hide latency of one memory type hidden behind the other.

If list is small enough, you can use registers directly (has to be compile-time known indices). But it increases register pressure and may decrease occupancy so be careful about this.

Some old cuda architectures (in case of fma operation) required one operand fetched from constant memory and the other operand from a register to achieve better performance in compute-bottlenecked algorithms.

In a test with 12000 floats as filter to be applied on all threads inputs, shared memory version with 128 threads-per-block completed work in 330 milliseconds while constant-memory version completed in 260 milliseconds and the L1 access performance was the real bottleneck in both versions so the real constant-memory performance is even better, as long as it is similar-index for all threads.

Comment: Actually, I find out later, for different thread reading different data, but different block reads same value, maybe texture memory is the best choice...It is designed for cached this kind of memory reading~